# Chrome extentsion модификация DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, chrome-extension, userjs

Пишу расширение под Chrome, нужно менять некоторые надписи, картинки. Но, до изменения видно старый элемент. Решил проблему скрытием элемента средствами CSS, через задание блоку "display: none". Но пока отобразится элемент проходит некоторое время, и это не слишком хорошо смотрится, хоть и лучше чем без этого.

Какие еще есть варианты для изменения страницы?

В контент скрипте, подключаю js примерно так:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(filePath);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

**Страница уже полностью загружена...**

Сам content script загружается: "run_at": "document_start"

> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any
>   files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other
>   script is run.

Comment: То есть у вас страница загружается и спустя довольно большой промежуток времени отрабатывает дополнение? На каком событии код отрабатывает?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов обновил...

Comment: А тот же код, но без $(document).on('ready', ...) не работает ли достаточно быстро?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Если вызвать синхронный alert, то страница на тот момент пуста. Более детально пока что не смотрел

Comment: А, ну все правильно, это я вчера криво прочитал: событие document_start срабатывает до (!!!) появления DOM. Попробуйте в коде аддона повесить ваш код через addEventListener на "load" или "pageshow". У меня для мозиллы аддон висел на "pageshow" и менял страницу незаметно.